# Hover effects in li class

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place hover image on my menu `li` but I don't know where I have been doing wrong.

Here is my CSS code and HTML link up.

Can anyone please help me point out my mistake?

```css
.topmenu1 {
  background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0px;
  left: -84px;
  width: 185px;
}

.topmenu1 a {
  width: 210px;
}

#topmenu1 a:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001over.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav id="category" class="drawer_block pc">
  <ul class="category-nav">
    <li class="topmenu1">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu2">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu3">
      <a href="#" onlick="window.open(`#`)"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu4">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu5">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu6">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu7">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And this is my website [azlily](http://azlily.awe.jp/eccube_1/) Where I have been trying to place a hover image on the menu bar.

Comment: The hover element in css has the 'id' (#) selector. I don't find topmenu1 as id of an element in the given code.Shouldn't the code be `.topmenu1 a:hover {
 background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001over.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}` ?

Comment: Use `.tomenu1 a:hover` instead of `#tomenu1 a:hover`

Comment: added !important too. and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already defined `background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);` property and `background` property can't be overridden by `background-image` property. so try adding `!important`. Try this code.

```
.topmenu1 a:hover {
    background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001over.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

Comment: topmenu1 is class not id so `.` and not `#`

Comment: Thank you very much. important tag, did it

Comment: Can u plz chck the site again, hover image is on. But why is it moving? Like whenever I hover it, text seems to go slight in right handside.

Comment: Its because you have this css `.topmenu1{background-position: 50% 0px;}`. Change it to this and it would work. `.topmenu1{background-position: 0 0px;}

Answer (score 1):

You assigned a image in `li` tag and hover in `<a>` tag, so that image not display.

Try hover on li tag:

```
.topmenu1:hover {
    background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001over.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: topmenu1 is class not id so `.` and not `#`

Comment: this didnt work until I added !important But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have this 
`.category-nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);}` snippet in your css which is overriding the hover effect of your `.topmenu1 a:hover`

and also there should be `.topmenu1` insted of `#topmenu1`. but i think its a typo in a question..

Try this by adding `!important` after background image..

```
.topmenu1 a:hover {
background-image: url(../img/img_upload/mainmenu001over.png) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: Can u plz chck the site again, hover image is on. But why is it moving? Like whenever I hover it, text seems to go slight in right handside.

Comment: for that you have to change the structure of the menu you have added image as a menu item and adding another image on hover... So i suggest you to ask another question for that and please accept the answer as correct if it solved your current question..